# Buy Till You Die(BTYD) - Model Validation in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes

I have used the BTYD Package in R to estimate the number of transactions that a customer is expected to make in the future. I have 2 questions:
1) Is the number of transactions always a non-integer value?
2) How do you validate the performance of the BTYD Model. I have made some R plots using the functions pnbd.PlotFrequencyInCalibration, pnbd.PlotFreqVsConditionalExpectedFrequency and pnbd.PlotRecVsConditionalExpectedFrequency. What exactly is the method used to validate the performance of BTYD Model? Can these plots be considered a measure of checking the performance of the model?[image] [image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1) The number of predicted transactions will either be an estimated # of transactions or a probabilistic value as a function of the form of the model. See the comments below for some clarification of how different models work and develop predictions.

2) Validation is dealt with in this paper on the BTYD model... https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BTYD/vignettes/BTYD-walkthrough.pdf Here's a quote (p. 10):

> To validate that the model works, we need to divide the data up into a
>   calibration period and a holdout period.

The subsequent discussion walks through this issue quite thoroughly.

Comment: re (1):  Isn't a number of predicted transactions *always* a "summary statistic"? Why must a prediction of a count always be an integer?  The vignette you reference doesn't seem to think it must be: in section 3.3, "Individual Level Estimations," none of the examples produces an integral estimate or prediction.

Comment: @whuber it's quite possible I'm mistaken but aren't the model predictions for each individual unit of analysis?

Comment: I don't see how that makes a difference.  As an extreme example, consider predicting whether it will rain or shine tomorrow: a binary event. If we were to insist that the prediction be definite, we would lose the nuance of being able to provide a probability.  Predictions and estimates of any other discrete quantity suffer similar problems--albeit not to such extremes--when they are constrained to be discrete, too. Predictions such as "this shopper will make 1.7 future purchases," when suitably understood, are demonstrably superior to predicting either 1 or 2 future purchases.

Comment: There's the confusion. I thought models such as the NBD made integer level predictions, not probabilistic ones

Comment: I wouldn't universally rule out that possibility--I had to check the vignette to be sure it wasn't constraining itself in that way.  But the emphasized "always" in your statement (1) seems a little hyperbolic :-).

Comment: That is true in light of your comments should I edit or delete the answer? If you're going to down vote it then I prefer to delete it

Comment: The choice is yours either to improve your answer or delete it.  I hope it's obvious, from the very fact of our dialog, that I value the other information you have provided, so I'm hoping for the former.

Comment: Ok I'll edit it but it will take some time before I'll be able to do this

Comment: Thank you for the response. The paper did help in the validation.
However, the doubt in the first question still remains. So, What I want to do is - I want to compare a customer's actual number of transactions in the holdout period to the one predicted by the BTYD Model. For eg- If a customer is making 0 transactions in the holdout period and the model is predicting 0.14 transactions. So, how exactly do I validate the model based on this result? How do I say that my model is working? So, instead of getting an expected value is there a way to get Maximum likely integer value of that estimation?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been using the library. The y axis is the mean expected transaction count for the model (mean of decimals), and the mean transaction count for the actual (mean of integers, since these are known counts). I agree, it makes no sense to only predict integers. You can just round them off if you like, but beware of introducing a cross sectional bias. If they’re mostly small positive values (like 0.1) rounding them all down will introduce a negative bias. Another solution: round up or down randomly, according to the fractional part.